# Finding the four-velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, acceleration

I'm a math student who also takes physics classes despite being pretty clueless in it. The first homework assignment is due in a few days and our professor failed to explain some of the terms used in the homework. The task is as follows:

We consider the world line $\underline x(\lambda)=\begin{pmatrix}a\sinh(\lambda)\\a\cosh(\lambda)\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$.

The first task was to show that this describes a hyperbole, I managed to do that. The second task is to show that the absolute value of the four-velocity $\underline u$ is constant. I don't understand how to find the four-velocity (our professor never mentioned this term in the lecture) of this world line. Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-velocity#Components_of_the_four-velocity (I also would much rather use a book, but our professor also failed to provide us with proper literature suggestions, instead he just trash-talked some books but didn't say which were actually good)) says that the first component of a four-vector is always $ct$ (if I understand correctly, which I probably do not), but in my world line, it is not, it's $\sinh$.

So: How do I find the four-velocity of this world line?

And further: What exactly is the absolute value of $\underline u$? Is it $\sqrt{t^2+x^2+y^2+z^2}$ or $\sqrt{t^2-x^2-y^2-z^2}$?

Comment: For four velocity consider differentiating with respect to the proper time, and then relate this to the parameter lambda via the invariant space time interval

Comment: @lux You mean $\left\vert\frac{d\underline x}{d\tau}\right\vert=\left\vert\frac{d\lambda}{d\tau}\frac{d\underline x}{d\lambda}\right\vert=...$? If so, which absolute value do I use? If it's the Lorentz-value, $\cosh^2(\lambda)-\sinh^2(\lambda)$ nicely cancels out, but I'm not sure. And how do I relate $\lambda$ to $\tau$ (proper time)? I don't see the connection to $(\Delta s)^2=(\Delta ct)^2-(\Delta x)^2$. We didn't even introduce this equation in the lecture (yet?).

Comment: That's the right idea: in the rest frame of the particle your $ds^2 = c^2d\tau^2$....but this relationship is invariant